# Heroku logs says: "No web processes running"

Tags: django, heroku

I made a website with django and tried deploying it using Heroku. After deploying, I can't access to it and Heroku log shows the following error :

```
at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pur-beurre-oc8.herokuapp.com request_id=9e33d4c8-83d6-4214-baf8-e4d1023b43ff fwd="176.134.6.63" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

After looking through some similar problems, I tried:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

and got:

```
Scaling dynos... !
 ▸    Couldn't find that process type (web).
```

I tried to remove and add buildpacks:

```
heroku buildpacks:clear
heroku buildpacks:add --index heroku/python
```

but this last command return to me:

```
Error: Expected an integer but received: heroku/python
    at Object.parse (/snap/heroku/3832/node_modules/@oclif/parser/lib/flags.js:17:19)
    at Parser._flags (/snap/heroku/3832/node_modules/@oclif/parser/lib/parse.js:152:49)
    at Parser.parse (/snap/heroku/3832/node_modules/@oclif/parser/lib/parse.js:113:28)
    at Object.parse (/snap/heroku/3832/node_modules/@oclif/parser/lib/index.js:25:27)
    at Add.parse (/snap/heroku/3832/node_modules/@oclif/command/lib/command.js:83:41)
    at Add.run (/snap/heroku/3832/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-buildpacks/lib/commands/buildpacks/add.js:7:36)
    at Add._run (/snap/heroku/3832/node_modules/@oclif/command/lib/command.js:44:31)
```

So I do not know what I'm doing wrong

My Proficle is like this:

```
web: gunicorn pur_beurre.wsgi
```

I tried to change Procfile like this:

```
web: gunicorn pur_beurre:app
```

or this:

```
web gunicorn pur_beurre:app
```

but `heroku ps:scale web=1` still not working

**Edit**

My Procfile was not in my app’s root directory, so I moved it and now `heroku ps:scale web=1` returns:

```
Scaling dynos... done, now running web at 1:Free
```

But I still have the error:

```
at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pur-beurre-oc8.herokuapp.com request_id=8cc800fa-cd49-43a9-8fc5-babf0028ca1f fwd="176.134.6.63" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: There's something wrong with your `Procfile`. Are you sure it contains what you say it does? Your last example is missing a `:`, which won't work. If it does contain what you say, make sure it's using Unix-style line endings. Make sure to commit that file and include it when you push; it needs to be included in your application slug with the right content.

Comment: what is Unix-style line ? right now my Procfile contains this line: `web: gunicorn pur_beurre:app` and I made a commit before pushing

Comment: Well it's not working. The `web:` in that file is supposed to define a `web` process type, but Heroku is telling you that you don't have one configured. Is there a newline at the end of the file? A [Unix-style newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation) is just a linefeed character. Windows uses carriage-return followed by linefeed. Any decent text editor should be able to convert between the two. Is your file called `Procfile` _exactly_, with the same casing and no file extension? Is it in the root directory (very top level) of your repository?

Comment: @Chris my file is called `Procfile` exactly yes and at the begining it wasn't at the root directory but I moved it and I edit my question

Comment: Are you binding to the right IP address and port? The port needs to come from the `PORT` environment variable. Are you using [`django-heroku`](https://pypi.org/project/django-heroku/)?

Comment: @Chris I am not using django-heroku, should I install it ? I don't now if I am binding to the right IP address and port

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201726/discussion-between-yacine-rouizi-and-chris).

Comment: @YacineRouizi Is your problem solved now? If yes, would you please explain what did you do? I'm stuck in the last kind of error you mentioned in your question.

Comment: @AK12 I don't remember what exactly I did, but I just checked my `Procfile` file and it's like this: `web: gunicorn pur_beurre.wsgi --log-file - --log-level debug` may be this solved my problem, I hope its going to help you